# delete node:<none> docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

```
REPOSITORY   TAG            IMAGE ID            CREATED       SIZE
node         13.8           e0e011be5f0f        20 minutes    1.18GB
node         <none>         e0e011be5f0f        7 days ago    942MB
```

need to remove only image - `node:<none>`

```
docker rmi node:<none>
```

syntax error

```
docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc
```

return empty

```
docker images -q -a | xargs docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}{{range $rt := .RepoTags}} {{$rt}} {{end}}'|grep -v ':'
```

return empty

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep none);
```

error: image has dependent child images

`node:13.8` depends on `node:<none>` ?

I have several projects on one server. And I want to make the names of the images unique for everyone so that you can delete and install images for a specific project.

image examples:

`project-name1-node-js:13.8`

`project-name2-node-js:13.8`

`project-name3-node-js:13.8`

But here is some incomprehensible `<none>` with dependency. This is official image of [node js](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` command we can find the value under `IMAGE ID` column, and then we can run the `docker rmi` on the `IMAGE ID` value.

`docker rmi $(docker images -a | grep "<none>" | awk '{ print $3 }')`

**Continuation:**
I just observed in your question it is the same IMAGE ID for tagged and untagged images of node. So, my guess is you should delete it based on the digest rather than image id.

`docker rmi $(docker images -a --digests=true | awk '$2 == "<none>" { print $1"@"$3}')`

Try adding -f at the end if you wanna try forcing the delete.

Comment: Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete f606891dff93 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images

Comment: My bad didn't realize you're having the dependent child images issue. Thought it was simple not able to find the right value to delete. Lemme research a little more.

Comment: you can combine the `awk` and `grep` command: `docker images -a | awk '$2 == "<none>" { print $3}'`

Comment: Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete f606891dff93 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images

Comment: I think what needs to happen is to delete by digest and not just the tag or image id. I updated the answer, try it.